# Simplifying a recursive expression

Tags: recursion

Let $p_n = \frac{1}{6}\left(p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} + p_{n-3} + p_{n-4} + p_{n-5} + p_{n-6} \right)$.

Let $p_0 = 1$ and $p_k = 0$ for $k < 0$.

Using this recursive equation, is there a simple way to obtain the following expressions, in particular for $p_3$ and onward?

$$p_1 = \frac{1}{6}, \quad p_2 = \frac{1}{6}\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right), \quad p_3 = \frac{1}{6}\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^2$$

$$p_4 = \frac{1}{6}\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^3, \quad p_5 = \frac{1}{6}\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^4, \quad p_6 = \frac{1}{6}\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^5$$

$$p_7 = \frac{1}{6}\left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{6}\right)^6 - 1 \right)$$

I'm able to derive these directly via algebraic manipulations of the equation for $p_n$, but this gets messy beyond $p_3$ so I'm hoping someone can describe a more elegant approach.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) for the general approach.  It involves solving a sixth degree polynomial here, so you may be in for numerics.

Comment: Write:
 
 $$p_{n+1}=\frac{1}{6}(p_n+\cdots+p_{n-5})=\frac{p_n}{6}+\frac{1}{6}(p_{n-1}+\cdots+p_{n-6})-\frac{p_{n-6}}{6}$$
 hence
 
 $$p_{n+1}=\frac{7}{6}p_n-\frac{p_{n-6}}{6}$$ but I do not know if this is of some help.

Comment: I made a spreadsheet and it seems to converge on $\frac 27$

Comment: May I suggest you remove $p_7$. It could be confusing. This is a nice problem leading to a conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing, we have (for sure)
$$p_n=\frac {a_n}{6^n}$$ and the $a_n$ correspond to the sequence
$$\{1,1,7,49,343,2401,16807,70993,450295,2825473,17492167\}$$ which is not identified by $OEIS$.

Coefficients $a_n$ *seem* to vary exponentially but I did not find any way to make the realtion explicit.

In any manner, the solution of 
$$p_n = \frac{1}{6}\left(p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} + p_{n-3} + p_{n-4} + p_{n-5} + p_{n-6} \right)$$ is given by 
$$p_n=c_0+\sum_{i=1}^5 c_i \,r_i^n$$ where the $r_i$ are the roots of the quintic polynomial
$$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5=0$$ One of them is real and four are complex conjugate.

The best I have able to do is to compute the $r_i$'s and to make them rational to get
$$r_1\sim-\frac{2316}{3455}\qquad r_{2,3}\sim -\frac{405}{1078}\pm\frac{65 }{114}i\qquad r_{4,5}\sim \frac{223}{758}\pm\frac{131 }{196}i$$

**Edit**

Computing the $a_n$ up to $n=30$ and performing a quick and dirty linear regression for
$$\log(a_n)=\alpha + \beta n$$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence
   Interval} \\
 \alpha & -1.29097167 & 0.01606328 &   \{-1.32437708,-1.25756626\} \\
 \beta & +1.79344429 & 0.00081322 &   \{+1.79175311,+1.79513548\} \\
\end{array}$$ and $\beta$ is "clearly" $\log(6)$. Fixing $\beta$ at this value leads to 
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence
   Interval} \\
 \alpha & -1.25980243 & 0.00617784 &   \{-1.27264996,-1.24695490\} 
\end{array}$$ and $e^\alpha$ is very close to $\frac 2 7$ as given by @Ross Millikan.

**Update**

In fact, if we consider the shorter sequences
$$p_n^{(k)}=\frac 1 k \sum_{i=1}^{k}p_{n-i}^{(k)}$$ with
$$p_0^{(k)}=1 \quad p_1^{(k)}=\frac 1 k\quad p_2^{(k)}=\frac{1}{k}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\quad p_3^{(k)}=\frac{1}{k}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2\quad \cdots$$ for which the general term can be computed,
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{n\to \infty } \,p_n^{(k)}=\frac 2 {k+1}}$$

Comment: The characteristic equation with the factor $\frac 16$ is $x^6=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)/6$.  This has a root of $x=1$ and all others with smaller real part.  It seems to converge to $\frac 27$

Comment: @RossMillikan. Thanks for your comment ! It gave me the idea of working the shorter recurrence relations and a funny conjecture.